# How to download attachments from on-premise exchange server using client-side Office JS API or any other JS?

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js

I have developed a Outlook web add-in which reads the mail and meeting/appointment content from the mailbox using Office JS API. I am able to retrieve all the contents using javascript API except the attachments for which I am using the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices nuget package to download the attachments in my asp.net mvc based Outlook web add-in.

Since this functionality for retrieving is done in server side code, it **does not work for on-premise exchange servers where the exchange APIs are not accessible publicly on internet**.

Is there any other way to retrieve and save the attachments using client side code / JavaScript so that I do not need my client to expose the on-prem exchange URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no other way to retrieve and save the attachments. However, it looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. [Please upvote the existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/14141102-retrieve-attached-files-in-the-composer-app-using). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thank you for the information. However the link you posted has disabled the voting. Looks like we have to stay away from attachments when working with on-prem servers.